# After ajax rerun php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an select menu that submits without reloading the page as follows:

```
<select id="option" name="option">
<option value="15">15/option>
<option value"30">30</option>
<option value"90">90</option>
</select>
```

It will submit to the current page as follows, without reloading the page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#option').change(function(){
        var option_val = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: "$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];",
        data: "option="+option_val,
       success: function(data)
        {
           window.alert(data)
        }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The result of a change in the option menu is an popup window with all the code of the page echoed back.

What i want to do on the page is use the $_POST['option'] that is submitted and recalculate a price for example

```
<body>
//some code and div's
<?php
if (isset($_POST['option'])) {
    $option = $_POST['option'];
$price= $row_product['price'] + $option;
echo $price;
} ?>
</body>
```

The are several places where I would like to use the submitted option value

Any help welcome
Sorry if it is very obvious

Comment: is this works for you??? See the ajax call on our browser console and can you make ajax call to the same page using `url: "$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];",`???

Comment: `url: "$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];"` doesn't look correct. You're not echoing those PHP variables. JS will try to post to that string as an url.

Comment: You can't do that. You should have only a piece of page that doesn't reload

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I think he prints that javascript with PHP

Comment: @TonySamperi How would you print that code block with PHP and still get those variables parsed, in it's current state? How ever you twist and turn it, I can't see a way for it to be parsed correctly.

Comment: Maybe you're right...

Comment: @TonySamperi, what would be the best way to call to the same page, sorry I thought that would be correct as I tried url: "" as well

Comment: Add <?php echo to your URL.

Comment: it's better to post to a different URL which just handles that specific request, rather than mixing it up in the same place that generates HTML. Separate your business logic from your presentation.

Comment: @ADyson would you be able to show me how that would work. Does it mean i have to make a different page that does the calculation. But how would I get that back into my page without a refresh and not in a specific div as I want to use the option value on different places. Thanks for looking

Comment: yeah you just make another PHP script which accepts the option value and echoes the answer (and nothing else). Essentially you're building an API.

Answer (score 1):

The only way is making a PHP page that does the calculation

**HTML/page1.php**

```
<select id="option" name="option">
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="90">90</option>
</select>
<div id="dynamic">
    <p>DEFAULT CONTENT</p>
</div>
```

**HTML/page2.php**

```
$option = 0;
if(isset($_GET["option"])){
    $option = $_GET["option"];
}
//do calculations
echo "<my-html-stuff>lorem ipsum</my-html-stuff>";
```

**JS**

```
var dynamic = $("#dynamic");
$('#select').on("change", function() {
   var selected = $(this).val();
   dynamic.load("page2.php?option=" + selected, function() {
       dynamic.html("<p>CONTENT OPTION "+selected+"</p>");
   });
});
```

Fiddle ==> https://jsfiddle.net/tonysamperi/4dbwwn3g/

**WITH JSON**

**page2.php**

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$option = 0;
if(isset($_GET["option"])){
     $option = $_GET["option"];
}
$response = ["result" => $option];
echo json_encode($response);
```

**JS**

```
$('#select').on("change", function() {
   var selected = $(this).val();
   $.get("page2.php?option=" + selected, function(response) {
       //do stuff with data
       console.debug("RESPONSE", response);
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, the problem is it is all echoed back as in a div, what I wanted is just to use the posted value of the option. Do you know if that is possible at all

Comment: I made some adjustments. Check'em out please.
Anyway the only way to do what you ask is this way.

Comment: Unless you make page2.php echo JSON data and use it

Comment: Would I still have to do this in a div or can I just recall $_POST['option']  its just I wanted to display the calculated values at several places and use them in different ways depending on the value chosen. Sorry to be a pain

Comment: would you be able to show me as I haven't got a clue where to start or point me in the right direction. Thanks again so much

Comment: so sorry I can't get that to work. I made a new page as suggest and used the exact code as you described option value X 2. There fore I was hoping to echo out in the page <?php echo $_GET['option'] ?> however i for no response. Thanks for you help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146682/discussion-between-tony-samperi-and-ria).